# Regular expression with ® symbol

Tags: regex, notepad++

Right now I have a regular expression to pick up most characters

```
([/\w\.-]+)$
```

However I would like it to also be able to find phrases with the ® symbol such as sdj-0s®. The ® character can appear anywhere any number of times. For example, searching for "www.samplesite.com/eng/sdj-0s®-wer®". Ideally we'd like to account for other possible Unicode characters as well.

What would be the best regex expression to achieve this?

Comment: So... add it - `([/®\w.-]+)$`? What is your problem?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to open it up to all special symbols at once (such as copyright and trademark symbols) or do we have to individually add them to the regex?

Comment: Add them to the regex. Or try `\p{S}` that stands for all Unicode symbols.

Comment: There is no such thing as a duplicate of "_What does this regex mean ?_".  Some info: you realize by adding the `$` you tell the engine to match those characters (in a pack) from that character class, _at the end of the string_  (and nowhere else) ? Is that what you intend ?

Comment: [Ediit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51937440/edit) your question and add sample lines and expected result.